# Maximum number of distinct inversions in an array

Tags: sorting, recurrence

Given an array A of n integers, we say that a pair of indices i<j∈[n] is an inversion in A if A[i]>A[j]. What is the maximum number of distinct inversions that A can have?

Is it 
a) n - 1 
b) n 
c) n(n−1)/2 
d) n^2 
e) n(n−1)(2n−1)/6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's obviously possible for *all* pairs of distinct indices to be inversions (if the entire array is in reverse order, e.g.: [5,4,3,2,1]). And it's obviously not possible for *more than all* pairs of distinct indices to be inversions.

So the question is: how many pairs of distinct indices are there?

If you arrange them geometrically, the pattern is pretty clear:

```
(1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5)
      (2,3) (2,4) (2,5)
            (3,4) (3,5)
                  (4,5)
```

(Note that I didn't include e.g. `(2,1)`, since that's the same two indices as `(1,2)`.)

Such numbers are called *[triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)*, for obvious reasons. Wikipedia gives a formula, but be sure not to confuse the *n* in its formula with the *n* in your problem statement. (They are slightly different. You'll need to do a small amount of algebra.)